# Атрибут data-* использование

Tags: html5

Для чего нужен, и влияет ли на поведение элементов на сайте?

Comment: Для использования вами в любых целях. Не влияет, если вы их никак не используете.

Comment: Очень хорошей практикой в разработке веб-приложения считается хранение всех данных в DOM. Если вы будете разбрасывать их по переменным в коде, то структура данных может легко превратится в вермишель.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

При данной анимации я использовал data-атрибуты, чтобы задать значение, до которого будет заполняться круг. Можете заметить, что у каждого второго `circle` есть data-атрибут `data-circle`. В js я получаю эти числа и работаю с ними

```js
function start() {

    let reqAnimFrame = (function() {
        return requestAnimationFrame       ||
               mozRequestAnimationFrame    ||
               webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
               oRequestAnimationFrame      ||
               msRequestAnimationFrame     ||
        function(callback) {
            setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
        }
    })();

    let dataCircle = document.querySelectorAll('.progressbar__thumb');

    function setProgress(percent, selector) {
        let circle = selector.querySelector('.progressbar__thumb');
        let total = Math.PI * circle.r.baseVal.value;
        circle.style.strokeDasharray = `${total*percent/100} ${total*(1-percent/100)*2}`;
        selector.querySelector('text').innerHTML = '<tspan>' + percent.toFixed(0) + '</tspan>%';
    }

    function circle(final, i) {
        let number = -1;
        i++;
        let selector = '.progress__container:nth-child(' + i + ')';
        let mainSelector = document.querySelector(selector);
        let myReq = null;
        function circleStep() {
            myReq = reqAnimFrame(circleStep);
            setProgress(number, mainSelector);
            if (number >= final) {
                cancelAnimationFrame(myReq);
            }
            number++;
        }
        circleStep();
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < dataCircle.length; i++) {
        let num = dataCircle[i].getAttribute('data-circle');
        circle(num, i);
    }

}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    start();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans&display=swap');

*, *:before, *:after {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 margin: 0;
 color: black;
 font-size: 16px;
 font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

.cards__progress__bar {
 display: -webkit-flex;
 display: -moz-flex;
 display: -ms-flex;
 display: -o-flex;
 display: flex;
 -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -moz-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
 -o-flex-wrap: wrap;
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-around;
 max-width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.progress__container {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.progressbar__track {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #ededed;
 stroke-width: 2px;
}

.progressbar__thumb {
 fill: transparent;
 stroke: #ff0036;
 stroke-width: 2px;
 transform-origin: center;
 stroke-dasharray: 0 1;
 transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.progressbar text {
 font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 400;
}

.progressbar text tspan {
 fill: #ff0036;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="cards__progress__bar">

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="100" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="90" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="80" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

  <div class="progress__container">
    <svg class="progressbar" viewbox="0 0 64 64">
      <circle class="progressbar__track" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <circle class="progressbar__thumb" data-circle="70" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="30"></circle>
      <text x=32 y=33 text-anchor=middle dominant-baseline=middle></text>
    </svg>
  </div> <!-- .progress__container -->

</div> <!-- .cards__progress__bar -->

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```